# sql - select row from group based on multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table like:

```
| ID    | Val |
+-------+-----+
| abc-1 |  10 |
| abc-2 |  30 |
| cde-1 |  10 |
| cde-2 |  10 |
| efg-1 |  20 |
| efg-2 |  11 |
```

and would like to get the result based on the **substring(ID, 1, 3)** and **minimum value** and ist must be **only the first** in case the Val has duplicates

```
| ID    | Val |
+-------+-----+
| abc-1 |  10 |
| cde-1 |  10 |
| efg-2 |  11 |
```

the problem is that I am stuck, because I cannot use **group by substring(id,1,3), ID** since it will then have again 2 rows (each for abc-1 and abc-2)

Comment: U can group by substring(id,1,3) instead of substring(id,1,3),id. That will work...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
WITH
  sorted
AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY substring(id,1,3) ORDER BY val, id) AS sequence_id
  FROM
    yourTable
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sorted
WHERE
  sequence_id = 1
```

Comment: +1 I was just writing an answer when I saw you'd beaten me to it. Very nice!

Comment: @RRZEurope - What it will do is take all records that have the same first three characters in their `id` field and group them together. It will order them so the lowest `val` comes first, and the lowest `id` comes first if the val's are tied. Then, the outer query will pick the first record from each group. What do the **real*** `id` values look like? Can there be more than three characters before the `-`? If so, the `SUBSTRING(id,1,3)` needs changing to match the behaviour of your data.

Comment: @RRZEurope - Look up ROW_NUMBER(). My comment above tries to explain it, but basically... The `PARTITION BY` clause creates groups. Within each group, the records are ordered according to the `ORDER BY` clause. Then all the rows within each group will get given sequential row_numbers assigned to them. (1,2,3,4,etc) in the first group, then starting again (1,2,3,4,etc) in the second group, etc, etc. This answer ensures that the rows that get the number `1` are always the rows that you want.

Comment: @RRZEurope - Stop adding comments and deleting them, I look like a schitzophrenic replying to questions that no longer exist ;)

Comment: Sorry, you are faster replying than me finishing asking the unnecessary follow-ups ;) OVER OUT!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(id,1,3),MIN(val) FROM Table1 GROUP BY SUBSTRING(id,1,3);
```

You were grouping the columns using both SUBSTRING(id,1,3),id instead of just SUBSTRING(id,1,3). It works perfectly fine.Check the same example in this below link.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd9fc/1

Comment: Except that the OP wants the ***whole*** `id` in the results, not just the substring(). And that `id` must be the one that corresponds to the `MIN(val)`.